# Saying Shemini Chag Haatzeret Haze in Shemona Esrei

Tags: tefilla, words, shmini-atzeres

Why do certain communities say *shemini chag haatzeret haze* and not *chag shemini atzeret haze* like all the other festivals *(chag hasukkot, chag hapesach).* Why is the word *chag* in the middle of the name?

Comment: Welcome Benza at MY and thank you for the question! Please note that we do not write in all caps.

Comment: You would see the answer if you would cite the whole phrase, as I added in Hebrew. It starts with "**ביום** השמיני", **on the 8th day** [of Succos, which is] Chag Atzeres. In other words, Hashmini refers to Beyom, not to Chag Atzeres.

Comment: @alberko the phrase is ותתן לנו... את יום שמיני חג העצרת הזה and Shmini might refer to Yom, but that's not so conclusive

Comment: @DoubleAA It's simple Hebrew. Why "might"? Azeres is the Succos' 8th day.

Comment: @AlBerkon In Hebrew we call the 8th day of Sukkot שמיני עצרת. No one says they are visiting their uncle for עצרת. The word Yom might refer to the whole holiday name שמיני חג העצרת, just like Yom in יום חג המצות refers to the whole holiday name. That's the simplest understanding

Answer (score 4):

This is addressed by [R. Mordechai Yaffe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mordecai_Yoffe). He explains that the formulation that you suggest could imply that there are eight holidays in the year or that each day of Sukkot is considered it's own holiday, both of which are false:

**[Levush O.C. 668:1](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9223&st=&pgnum=252)**

> אבל אין לומר יום חג שמיני העצרת הזה שהיה משמעותו שהוא חג השמיני הנקרא
>   עצרת וכו' וא"כ היה משמע לשונו שהוא החג השמיני וזה שקר שאין לנו שמנה
>   חגים בשנה וגם אין לומר שקאי על הסוכות לבדו ונאמר שכל יום מימי החג הוא
>   חג בפני עצמו שזה גם כן שקר כי אין נקרא חג בפני עצמו אלא יום השמיני
>   לבדו שהוא חג בפני עצמו לענין פז"ר קש"ב

It should be noted, though, that some did/do have the formulation as you suggest, including [Rambam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maimonides):

**[Rambam Seder HaTefilot](https://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/2700.htm#44)**

> וכן בשמיני עצרת אומר את יום טוב מקרא קדש הזה את יום חג שמיני עצרת הזה
>   זמן שמחתנו

Answer (score 0):

Since Shemini Atzeres is the defined by "The 8th day abstinence (from work)" when we introduce the festival in Shemone esrei we say ...ותתן לנו את יום, we have to refer directly to the 8th day by saying יום שמיני then after we declare this 8th day is special to us because Yom tov :חג העצרת הזה.

If we said יום חג העצרת הזה one would mistakenly think its Shavuos which is also called עצרת

If we said יום חג עצרת שמיני הזה that would mean its the 8th festival, which is not true because there are only 2 Festivals 1 on the first day and 1 on the last day (in the Torah) in the middle one permitted to do Melacha.

If we said יום חג השמיני עצרת הזה that would also mean its the 8th festival, which is not true because there are only 2 Festivals 1 on the first day and 1 on the last day (in the Torah) in the middle one permitted to do Melacha.

Comment: The last day of Pesach is also called Atzeret. Maybe we'd think you meant that. And in Chul on the eighth day of Pesach it could be a real problem.

Comment: @doubleaa good question **excuse my ignorance** Pesach is called שְּׁבִיעִי עֲצֶרֶת as you quoted **not** שמיני עֲצֶרֶת. simchas torah in chutz laaretz is called shmini atzeres because in the time of the unfixed calender they thought it might be the 8th day no one calls it tshii atzereres, so too 8th day Pesach is called Shevii atzeres  because in the time of the unfixed calender they thought it might be the 7th day no one calls it Shmini Atzeres so there is no confusion

Comment: "If we said יום חג שמיני עצרת הזה that would also mean its the 8th festival" No it wouldn't. It would mean "this festival of Shmini Atzeret" as the OP says.

Comment: "said יום חג השמיני עצרת הזה" The OP specifically asked about יום חג שמיני עצרת הזה so why don't you address it directly. You're dancing around her question with your own assertions about what other options may mean